# How to remove a node and add a new one Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I need your help.

I'm trying to remove a node and load a new one after have dismissed the previous one.

Actually I was able to remove it using inside a separate func:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
```

But after that I'm recalling the function "addChild" the new node is not appearing on the scene.

```
 func addChild(object: String){
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

            let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(object)

            //reading
            do {
                scene = try SCNScene(url: path)
                node = scene.rootNode

            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}
        }
        counter += 1

    }
```

"addChild" is taking as a parameter an element of the array and the counter is moving the pointer to another element of the array after every time that the func is called.

EX: I have an array with two elements and I want that just for the first time the object to shown is always the first and then when I'm touching the object it will be removed and the func addChild must be called in this way the previous element is dropped from the array and the next one will be loaded thanks to the counter that is moving the pointer to the next element.

I don't know if my example was enough explanatory.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ofc it's getting inside because the first element is displayed in the scene...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed just recalling the "sceneView.scene = scene" inside the function, removing the element from the array every time that I'm calling the function removeChild.

func addChild(object: String){
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

```
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(object)

        //reading
        do {
            scene = try SCNScene(url: path)
            node = scene.rootNode
            sceneView.scene = scene
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }


}
```